# Python: 'module' object has no attribute 'getuid'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write my first django webapp, and it work fine with a simple view but as soon as I include my model, it starts to give the following error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'getuid'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/photos/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'module' object has no attribute 'getuid'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py in expanduser, line 321
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

I read that this might be because of circular import issue but I dont see anything in my model imports.

```
import logging
import sys
import os
import flickrapi

def get_photos_for_artist(artist=None):
        if not artist:
                logging.error('can not find photos for unknown artist')
                return None

        api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key)
        gen = flickr.walk(tags=artist, content_type=1, per_page=10)
        return gen

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

What could be causing this?

Django Logs say :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py in expanduser
    return path
i = path.find('/', 1)
if i < 0:
    i = len(path)
if i == 1:
    if 'HOME' not in os.environ:
        import pwd
        userhome = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir ...
    else:
        userhome = os.environ['HOME']
else:
    import pwd
    try:
        pwent = pwd.getpwnam(path[1:i])
```

Comment: You have not provided any useful information. For example, the code you post doesn't seem to correspond to an actual view. And Django prints a very useful debugging page when it encounters an error: you should look at that, if necessary paste the traceback here (click "switch to copy-and-paste view" first).

Comment: The error message is unambiguous: The function `os.getuid()` used by `posixpath.expanduser()` does not exist.  This is weird, since you seem to be using Mac OS X, which, beeing a Unix system, should provide `getuid()`.  Are you somehow messing with standard library modules?

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer, No I am not messing with standard system

Comment: Do you have a `os.py` in your directory?

Answer (score -2):

Try to check version of python and check python installation and PYTHONPATH variable. May be problim with enveroment, not code.